# How to get "FTP Host Name" and "FTP User Name" for windows azure custom domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have created a custom domain on windows azure, I need to upload file on newly created domain but I am not getting how can I get "FTP Host Name"  and "FTP User Name" for newly created domain. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Login to your [Azure Portal](http://manage.windowsazure.com) and navigate to the appropriate website.  Select the Dashboard option / tab and on the right hand side of the screen you'll find the FTP Host name for FTP and FTPS along with the FTP Username.  You can reconfigure the FTP / Deployment credentials from the 'Reset your deployment credentials'.

A final note: for non-programming questions you may find it more beneficial to post onto [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)